# Guice declarative vs method syntax

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm new to `Guice` and would like the know the meaning (or difference between the following):

```
@SessionScoped
public class Counter {
 int count = 0;
```

Does it everyone who has a `Counter` as a member will have the same `Counter` singleton instance?

what is the difference with this syntax? what is the meaning of this line if there is no `to()`?

```
bind(MySingleton.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

also:

Here is the code to init inhector:

public class ClientApplication {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector());        

        MyApplication app = injector.getInstance(MyApplication.class);

        app.sendMessage("Hi Pankaj", "pankaj@abc.com");
    }
 }
```

How do I init the injector when I don't have my own `main` method?

eg. running `Cucamber` or `Junit`?

Comment: `@SessionScoped` isn't the same as `Scopes.SINGLETON`.  Did you mean `@Singleton`?

Comment: no, I don't understand what's `@SessionScoped` then. And do `@Singleton` is the same as `Scopes.SINGLETON` ?

Comment: `@SessionScoped` lasts for the lifetime of an HTTP session if you're using Java servlets.  Its matching scope instance is `ServletScopes.SESSION`.  `@Singleton` is the annotation for `Scopes.SINGLETON`.

Comment: Can you check your spelling? Do you mean _Cucamber_ or _Cucumber_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To no `to()` question, it's equivalent of `bind(MySingleton.class).to(MySingleton.class)`, but this is done implicitly by guice.

To test with guice, I personally use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grouplens.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-test</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

The code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(GuiceTestRunner.class)
@TestModule(CoreModule.class)
public class EnvironmentSetupTest extends CamelTestSupport
```